# Ajax Calendarexternder with previous days disabled

Tags: calendarextender

I am working with Ajax's CalendarExtender and this is what I would like to accomplish.

I want to have a text and when a user clicks on the text box, I would like to pop up calendar with previous disabled (crossed out).

Would someone know or link to this sample code?

Thank you.